# VS Code puts parentheses when is no need of it

Tags: visual-studio-code

i am trying to make nested array but  VS CODE puts parentheses automaticly at the wrong place:
i am trying to write this code:
`const nested = [1, 2 [3, 4]]`
but when i hit command + s vs code automaticly converts my code into this: `const nested = [1, (3)[(5, 7)]]`
i already tried to modify "editor.Auto Closing Overtype" to auto or never or always but it doesn't help.
how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: I don't know what language this is supposed to be, but it looks odd.  Shouldn't there be a comma after "2"?  And do you really mean that VS code changes the actual numbers?

Comment: disable your `format on save`

Answer (score 0):

it seems I forgot to put coma after the first element of an array, that's why Vs Code acted like that. `const nested = [1, 2 [3, 4]]`, there is no coma after "2"